# Can we trade in Australian Stock Market outside of regular trading hours?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, australia, after-hours-trading

ASX regular trading hours are from 10 AM to 4:10 PM (including CSPA). I want to know if we can trade outside of these hours i.e. before 10 AM or after 4:10 PM. I know we can place orders from 7AM to 10 AM but these orders are not executed until market opens at 10 AM.

For an example, we can trade in US market outside of regular market hours (9:30 to 4 PM). Form-T trades are executed from 4 AM to 9:30 AM during pre market hours, and 4 PM to 8 PM during after market hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

Some information about the market timing here:
https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/market-resources/trading-hours-calendar

Comment: Yes, it says, ASX does not trade orders during Pre market. But it seems off-exchange trading takes place during "Adjust" and "Adjust On" sessions during after market hours. Not sure if these can be considered as eligible trade price during after hours.